# Fast Search within Ruby on Rails Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, dynamic-arrays

I'm having a huge array of Hashes. Each Hash a detail about a company. When i search within this Array of Hashes. it is extremely slow. How i can improve its performance?

I'm using Select method with conditions to get the different companies based on status, and division like

```
companies.count { |company| company.sectors.include?('educational') && company.status == 'completed' }
```

**What is the best way to search from a huge hashes of arrays using ruby on rails ?**

Comment: The fastest way is to search inside database, with SQL queries

Comment: What about importing your data into a database and querying it? If your dataset doesn't change often it might be a good idea

Comment: You mean "huge arrays of hashes", I believe. Also, you have given too little info. How many search criteria you have? Do you always use the same set of search criteria? Why your current data structure is as is?

Comment: @Nermin: Most definitely not. At least not in general case. Most convenient perhaps, but fastest - no.

Comment: This might not be the most helpful comment but is there some sorting you can do before searching?

Answer (score 0):

use SQL:

```
Company.where('selector like ? AND status = ?', '%educational%', 'completed').count
```

but you can use first for find `companies`

```
@companies = Company.includes(:my_associations).where(...)
```

than my sample `.where('selector like ? AND......`